# How and what files to ignore in a Flex Flash Builder project in a Git repository?

Tags: git, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have a Flash Builder project and it is in Git. There are files like /bin-debug and .actionScriptProperties that are showing up as pending. Should I be committing these?

What files do you ignore in your Flash Builder project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse project files:

- .project
- .settings

FlashBuilder specific project files:

- .actionScriptProperties
- .flexProperties (only for a non-library project)
- .flexLibProperties (only for library project)

Some more exotic FlashBuilder project files:

- .FlexUnitSettings (generated when running unit test from within FB)
- .externalToolBuilders (generated when using the web service generator tool)
- .model (generated when using the data modeling tool)

FlashBuilder default output folders:

- bin-debug (only for a non-library project)
- bin-release (only for a non-library project)
- bin (only for library project)

You should never commit IDE-related files. It makes it harder for other developers on your team to use the IDE of their choice. This is especially true if you work on an opensource project.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to ignore .project and .settings, but how am I supposed to get those files after cloning a project. The problem is: Flash Builder won't let me import a project without those files. What's the best practice to deal with it.

Comment: @IvanZamylin Just create a project (not import; a new project) in the root directory. Don't worry, this will not erase the files already in there. If the main source folder doesn't match FB's default (which is `src`), you may have to adjust this in the project properties. Also dependencies will have to be managed manually. To cope with this problem, you can use an automated build tool like [FlexMojos](https://github.com/velo/flexmojos) or [GradleFx](http://gradlefx.org/). You can commit this build script to Git, and the tool can setup your IDE project for you.

Comment: But what about references to external libraries etc

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Same answer: either configure them manually or have an automated build tool do it for you. I can think of a third option here though: you might put the swcs in the `libs` folder and commit that to git. FB has the `libs` folder on its build path by default. However you cannot use this third option for dependencies on other projects (unless you had an ANT script that copied the compiled swcs over before building).

Comment: Maybe, can you give us step by step how to import said project in Flash Builder after doing all the ignores? Maybe it's another question though it is part of this questions process?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts It depends on all the dependencies and other compiler options you may or may not have defined. I'd need a concrete case. I'd say it is a different question since it is not directly related to git.